# Magento 2.3: How can I get the customer ID with PHP?

Tags: module, cart, customer, magento2.3, extensions

I am trying to get the items of the cart as well as the customer ID in my Module. But the problem is that I don't know how to get the customer ID properly.

In the Moment I have this Code and it works:

```
<?php
// Get all items in cart
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Now, what do I need to add to get the Customer ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new to Magento but I am quite certain that this should be the solution.

```
$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
```

And then use this:

```
echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

This should yield you the perfect result

Comment: This is not good to use the object manager directly in the code.

Answer (score 5):

Please try with below code...

```
$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");

  echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

**I hope its work for you.**

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. You are the best.

Comment: Using observer, how to do that?

Comment: using observer, also try same code.

Answer (score 4):

This should be the right code:

```php
$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");

  echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

By using this **great** code it should work.

Therefore, the customer ID will get returned to you.

Answer (score 3):

I am quite certain that this should be the soltuon

```
  $customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
```

And then use this:

```
  echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

This should yield you the perfect result

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
public function getCustomerId(){
    $session = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    
    return $session->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Here, firstly you need to check customer is logged in or not:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
echo 'Customer ID: '.$this->getCustomerId();   
}
```

**Hope this will be better solution.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `getCustomerSession()` in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` to get customer data.

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$customerId = $cart->getCustomerSession()->getCustomerId();
```